# How to ignore command failure when running it using Fabric 2

Tags: python, fabric

In [Fabric 1](https://docs.fabfile.org/en/1.12.1/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) it looks like this:

```py
with settings(warn_only=True):
    run_commands_that_may_fail()
```

It is unclear how to implement it in [Fabric 2](https://www.fabfile.org/), [pyinvoke](http://docs.pyinvoke.org/en/latest/api/context.html#invoke.context.Context.cd) via context manager. [The upgrade docs](https://www.fabfile.org/) recommend replacing `warn_only` with `run.warn`. I've come up with:

```py
old_warn = c.config.run.warn
c.config.run.warn = True
try:
    run_commands_that_may_fail(c)
finally:
    c.config.run.warn = old_warn
```

Perhaps, there is a nicer way that is similar to Fabric's 1.

Comment: the new method for fabric 2 seems more pythonic (as in: extensive use of try-catch-finally), maybe such change was really the intended behavior?

Comment: Have you considered just making your own context manager to do this?

Answer (score 5):

As [Artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9445557/artemis) said, I think a context manager would be best here - unless you're happy to provide the kwarg for every specific call. For example:

```py
if c.run('test -f /opt/mydata/myfile', warn=True).failed:
    c.put('myfiles.tgz', '/opt/mydata')
```

Concerning the context manager, you could create a whole new config so you don't have to modify the original:

```py
import contextlib

import fabric

config = fabric.Config()
# set options


@contextlib.contextmanager
def run_with_warnings(old_config):
    new_config = old_config.clone()
    new_config.config.run.warn = True
    yield new_config


with run_with_warnings(config) as config_allowing_warning:
    run_commands_that_may_fail(config_allowing_warning)
```